# Unable to import cufflinks

Tags: python, plotly

Has anybody faced this error when importing cufflinks?
[image]

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: Clearly, you need to install [talib](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib).

Comment: BTW -- ensure that there's enough content included *as text* for someone to understand and answer your question even if image links break, or if someone is using a screen reader. This also ensures searchability -- Google will help someone find this if they have the same problem only if the essential parts of the question are present as text, not images.

Comment: (and as Sidon says -- there's just a partial traceback here, not an actual error message; if there were a different error that occurred while trying to import talib, there isn't enough information in the question here for us to know anything about it).

Comment: My apologies. I uploaded a wrong image! I uploaded the right one now. I am unable to install TA-Lib.

Comment: Is there a .whl file to install talib?

Comment: Win32 or Win64?

Comment: See http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib.

Comment: Thanks! Installed perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

All talib dependencies have now been removed. Studies have been rewritten in pure python.